# system shows All requested packages already installed.however i get error message when i import pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, torchvision

I installed pytorch using the following command as specified on their site: `conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch`. 
However, I tried using import torch and I get the following error:

```
'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\__init__.py", line 81, in <module>
    ctypes.CDLL(dll)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found'
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: do a pip freeze and check if pytorch is there

Comment: Are you sure this is the whole error traceback?  I was expecting to see a line like `import torch`, and I don't see it.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using a CUDA variant of PyTorch on a system that doesn’t have GPU driver installed. 
If you don’t have a Nvidia GPU card, please install the cpu-only package according to the commands on:

## Conda

```
conda install pytorch torchvision cpuonly -c pytorch
```

## Pip

```
pip install torch==1.5.0+cpu torchvision==0.6.0+cpu -f
```

Or:

```
conda install PyTorch -c PyTorch
```

Or:

```
pip3 install torchvision
```